# bash script convert output into array and remove duplicates

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a function which outputs a list of email addresses found in a large text file and outputs as follows:

```
Testing@outlook.com
Some_Email@gmail.com
Testing@outlook.com
Some_Email@gmail.com
John.Doe@test.com
Smith@hello.co.uk, orange123@testing.com
John.Doe@test.com
Smith@hello.co.uk, orange123@testing.com
contact@email.com
support@email.com, contact@email.com
```

I need to convert this output into a comma delimited array of email address that I can iterate over in a for loop, I also would like to remove duplicates.

I've tried a few variations of sed and not really been able to do what I want. Any tips would be brilliant.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: "Array" is a data structure, "comma delimited" describes a string. Data structures aren't delimited, they're abstract.

Comment: If you want help with your problem then please show your attempt in solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quick and dirty awk that will do this for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:blank:],]+"; OFS=","}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) a[tolower($i)]}
     END{s=""; for(i in a) s=s (s?OFS:"") i; print s}' file
```

This takes care of duplicate emails with different capitalisation. It does not sort the list.

If you want the order to be identical, I would do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:blank:],]+"; OFS=","}
     { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
         e=tolower($i)
         if (!(e in a)) { printf (p==0?"":OFS) "%s", e; a[e]; p=1 }
     }}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried replacing only '\n' with ',' ?  sort -u before running the sed would ensure unique values (no duplicates)

I copied your email list and stuck it into email.txt

```
sort -u email.txt -o email.txt && sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' email.txt
```

Here is the output of the file that I got from the above command

```
contact@email.com,John.Doe@test.com,Smith@hello.co.uk, orange123@testing.com,Some_Email@gmail.com,support@email.com, contact@email.com,Testing@outlook.com
```

using tr should work as well

```
tr '\n' ',' < email.txt > csv.out
```